# Faulty img tag not displaying images in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

One of our WordPress themes produces a strange tag due to some poorly written code. The tag is read fine by Chrome and Edge but Internet Explorer refuses to display the images.

This is how the tag is outputted in both Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
<img src="&lt;img width=" 806"="" height="605" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg 806w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-152x114.jpg 152w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-768x576.jpg 768w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-253x190.jpg 253w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-506x380.jpg 506w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-600x450.jpg 600w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-200x150.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 806px) 100vw, 806px">
```

Is there some kind of frontend script or code that I can apply so that Internet Explorer will show the images?

I can delete the src attribute using `$('.class').removeAttr('src')` but this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

For your viewing conveniece, I have included the url: https://www.staging1.prikkabelled.nl/referenties/

Comment: Targeting your image tag via the attributes will no doubt fail because your attributes are incorrect. Your `src` attribute contains a value of `&lt;img width=` meaning **806** means nothing which then had a domino effect on the rest of your attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your problem is not about the img tag itself, but what is before your img tag.

In chrome, I have inspected the source page, and I found this:

```
<img src="<img width="430" height="397" ...
```

I think you should watch source generated in your WYSIWYG editor or directly in your template

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

1. delete the src attribute, i.e. : *src="<img width="*
2. delete the *806"=""*

I think the above 2 should solve your problem.

Comment: I did jQuery('img.attachment-post-thumbnail.size-post-thumbnail.wp-post-image').removeAttr('src');
 jQuery('img.attachment-post-thumbnail.size-post-thumbnail.wp-post-image').removeAttr('806'); 

But this didn't solve the problem